# Check if string contains more than one word reg exp javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

i have a simple issue that i want to sort out. So basically i have a picture string that goes like this '10_aut_linen_male_less_student_work_yellow_n_cold.png' where

male = gender; n = weather ; cold = temperature.

Now i have those variables stored in a var. How do i check if ALL of those 3 variables are in the picture string?

Comment: Do you really need regex? Just call `.contains` 3 times for each variable

Comment: not sure what you are asking... Are you asking to check if the string in a variable happens to be in another string? Or are you asking to yank out the strings?

Comment: `str.includes('male') && str.includes('n') && str.includes('cold')`

Comment: i have alot of pictures and their names i store in a var called imgDirArray. Then i build a string based on user input with alot of vars including gender, weather, temperature. I first check if that built string equals picture string

Comment: if (imgDirArray.indexOf(imageString)>-1){ insert that image} if not i gotta check if those three vars are the same as the ones in the picture, and if all 3 of them are i list that picture and break out of the for loop.

Comment: so basically i just need to compare all 3 vars for every picture string and that is what i am having an issue with

Comment: @adaneo i was thinking of that, but the question is will that be fast enough in terms of comparing? Couse in some cases i will have alot of checking in for loop